# Can I use robots.txt to send the robots to a specific folder?

Tags: search-engine, robots.txt

So I have a regular website and a blog in the same domain. In the future I plan on buying a domain exclusively for the blog but for now this is the way I'll do it.

The blog is in the directory `/blog` and there are no links from the main site to the blog. So I presume robots just can't get there.

Is there a way to send robots to a particular directory using `robots.txt`?
Is there any other solution than putting a link in the main site?

Comment: Probably more suitable for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, there are so many stack exchange websites these days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use sitemaps to achieve that

> The **Robot Exclusion Standard**, also known as the Robots Exclusion
>   Protocol or robots.txt protocol, is a convention to prevent
>   cooperating web crawlers and other web robots from accessing all or
>   part of a website which is otherwise publicly viewable. Robots are
>   often used by search engines to categorize and archive web sites, or
>   by webmasters to proofread source code. The standard is different
>   from, but can be used in conjunction with, **Sitemaps, a robot inclusion
>   standard** for websites.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard